# multiple ajax calls : how to execute the next one after the current is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have that small simple Jquery script :

```
$(".div").each(function(){
 $.get("https://www.example.com/makeit.php" )
            .done(function( data ) {
                //fill a input field with data
        });
});
```

There are a lot of iterations and some calls fail with a 500 error. I think there are too many requests per seconde.
How to make my script continue to the next iteration after the get call is complete ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, the other code is a little bit complicate for me, it did not help me. Thanks to delete the duplicate tag.

Comment: Jew, can you update my post ? thank you jew :)